# See in jupyter lab when i collapse the cell the first comment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-console

in my personal pc i use jupyter lab and when i did collapse the cell i could see the first line comment like

[image: Collapse code comment]

i had some problem with anaconda and i reinstall it and now i see only the three point when i collapse.

I love some much the comment collapse and help me to much, idk how to reset and how i had done to set the first time.

[image: collapse code now]

Comment: I guess that you installed an older version of jupyterlab. The default anaconda archives still have outdated 3.x versions whereas conda-forge channel has 4.x